# How can I find the maximum across all variables corrresponding to the max in one variable?

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I have an xarray of daily data with a number of variables. I want to extract the maximum `q_routed` every year and the corresponding values of other variables on the day that the maximum `q_routed` happens.

```
    <xarray.Dataset>
    Dimensions:    (latitude: 1, longitude: 1, param_set: 1, time: 17167)
    Coordinates:
      * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1970-01-01 ...
      * latitude   (latitude) float32 44.5118
      * longitude  (longitude) float32 -111.435
      * param_set  (param_set) |S1 b''
    Data variables:
        ppt        (time, param_set, latitude, longitude) float64 ...
        pet        (time, param_set, latitude, longitude) float64 ...
        obsq       (time, param_set, latitude, longitude) float64 ...
        q_routed   (time, param_set, latitude, longitude) float64 ...
```

The command below gives me the maximum of **every** variable in a year, but that's not what I want.

```
ncdat['q_routed'].groupby('time.year').max( )
```

#### Trial

I tried this

```
ncdat.groupby('time.year').argmax('time')
```

which leads to this error:

```
ValueError: All-NaN slice encountered
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sort of operation, you probably want to use a custom reduce function:

```
def my_func(ds, dim=None):
    return ds.isel(**{dim: ds['q_routed'].argmax(dim)})


new = ncdat.groupby('time.year').apply(my_func, dim='time')
```

Now, `argmax` doesn't play nice when you have a full array of nans, so you may want to either only apply this function to locations with data or pre-fill the existing nans. Something like this could work:

```
mask = ncdat['q_routed'].isel(time=0).notnull()  # determine where you have valid data

ncdat2 = ncdat.fillna(-9999)  # fill nans with a missing flag of some kind
new = ncdat2.groupby('time.year').apply(my_func, dim='time').where(mask)  # do the groupby operation/reduction and reapply the mask
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joe.